# ASCIIZ String Assembly 8086 (Replacing Character)

Tags: string, assembly, ascii, x86-16

I want to delete and then add a character from an ASCII string in Assembly Language (8086). For example in the following code i want to delete the carriage return from the string and add the 0. As a matter of fact the interrupt 39h wants an ASCIIZ pathname but 0Ah adds a final carriage return character and not 0. How can I do it?

```
.model tiny

.data

    folderpath DB "",0

.code
    org 0100h

inizio:
    mov ah,0ah
    lea folderpath ,dx
    int 21h 

; HERE I WOULD LIKE TO MODIFY THE STRING

    lea dx, folderpath
    mov ah,39h
    int 21h

fine:
    mov AH,4Ch
    int 21h

end inizio
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input buffer must have a byte value of the maximum characters that the buffer can hold in the first byte. Plus another byte as a placeholder for the number of characters actually read and additional the amount of bytes for the string itself.

```
Format of DOS input buffer:
00h BYTE    maximum characters buffer can hold
01h BYTE    (call) number of chars from last input which may be recalled
    (ret) number of characters actually read, excluding CR
02h  N BYTEs    actual characters read, including the final carriage return
```

Example:

```
len = 10
Input_Buffer DB len, ?
folderpath   DB len+1 dup (" ")
```

After the input we can get the number of the characters for calculating the address of the carriage return and for to override it with a zero byte:
Calculating the offset of the carriage return byte = offset of "folderpath" + the number of chars from last input + 1:

```
lea si, Input_Buffer + 1         ; offset of number of chars from last input
xor ax,ax                        ; set ax to zero
mov al,[si]                      ; get the number of chars from last input
mov di,ax                        ; put it into an address register
mov BYTE PTR[di+folderpath+1], 0 ; override the carriage return(0Dh) with a zero byte
```

This instruction(using Intel syntax) does not exist:

```
lea folderpath ,dx
```

Use this one instead:

```
lea dx, Input_Buffer
mov ah, 0ah
int 21h
```

Hint: for a DOS *.com file are: CS=DS=ES, but for a DOS *.exe file we have to set the data segment register and we have to allocate a stack segment too.

Comment: Tasm return this error: "Illegal instruction for currently selected processor(s)" at the line 16 that is: "movzx di, [si]". I use the DOS*.com file. How can I fix it?

Comment: Ups my bad, this instruction does not exist. But we can fix it with these both instructions: "mov al, [si]" + "movzx di,al"

Comment: Another variation: "xor ax,ax" + "mov al,[si]" + "mov di,ax"

Comment: Sorry but, I didn't understand the final code that I've to use

Comment: Now i have edit the middle part of my answer above, for calculating the offset address of the carriage return byte for to replace it with a zero.